# What is the value of 'c' for the output of this function?

Tags: functions

Consider the function $α : \Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}, α(x) = x^2 + 1$. Given that $α([−1, 2]) = [c, 5]$, what is the value of $c$?

I said it was $2$ because all I did was plug in $-1$ in $x^2 + 1$. Am I correct?

Comment: The function is not monotone so you actually should sketch it out to find the minimum point.

Answer (score 1):

The lowest point of $\alpha$ is when $x=0$: $\alpha(0)=1$, so $$\alpha([-1,2])=[1,5].$$

Comment: ohh. Makes sense, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

$\alpha$ is a continuous function. So, it has a maximum and minumum values in $[-1,2]$.
$(i)$ Firstly, calculate $\alpha(c)$ for each critical point $c\in [-1,2]$;
$(ii)$ Secondly, find $\alpha(-1)$ and $\alpha(2)$
Then maximum and minumum value of $\alpha$ over the $[-1, 2]$ are just those calculated values.
 $\alpha$ has only critical point in this interval which is $0$. Because, $\alpha'(x)=2x=0$ if and only if $x=0$. 
Hence, $\alpha(0)=1$, $\alpha(-1)=2$, $\alpha(2)=5$.
Therefore, $1$ is a minumum value of $\alpha$ and $5$ is a maximum value of $\alpha$, so $c=1$ 
 We can use above method for any continuous function in any closed interval.